# CoreData - If something exists don't save it, if it doesn't exists then save it

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data

I have a single entity `Favourites` and it contains values such as `id`, `name` but the problem is that it is creating multiple copies of items and I wanted it to only store values if it is unique. How can I do this with Core Data?

Here is my code:

```
let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
                
let newFav = Favourites(context: context)

if let id = self.itemsViewModel.items?.results?[indexPath.item].id {
   newFav.id = id
}

if let name = self.itemsViewModel.items?.results?[indexPath.item].name {
   newFav.name = name
}

self.saveItem()
```

I do this in an alert and outside of that closure is my saveItem() function everything works but I am trying to save only one item with one id. I am thinking of checking if that `id` exists but I am not quite sure how would I do that with CoreData

```
func saveItem() {
        do {
            let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            print("Error saving context \(error)")
        }
    }
```

Comment: This looks like a design issue, why are you getting data from your view model instead of telling the view model to save the data? And what is your data source, haven't you already done a fetch of existing Favourites objects?

Comment: My view model does the job of fetching data from the api. I am fetching data in another view controller on favourites array

Comment: So you're downloading data from some external Api and storing it locally? Do you want to update existing objects?

Comment: I fetch data from the api the items are too many so I have created an option to favourite the item and store it in core data. That way the user don't have to scroll down a lot and just view the item if they have favourited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform a fetch with a distinct predicate and create a new record if the result is zero, for example

```
func saveItem(with id : Int32, name : String) {
    do {
        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
        let request : NSFetchRequest<Favourites> = Favourites.fetchRequest()
        request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id == %d AND name == %@", id, name)
        let numberOfRecords = try context.count(for: request)
        if numberOfRecords == 0 {
            let newFav = Favourites(context: context)
            newFav.name = name
            newFav.id = id
            try context.save()
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error saving context \(error)")
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a few more things in my favourites data a bool to check if it is favourited and couple of string values I can use this example but I am not sure what I would do with this part ```format: "id == %d AND name == %@``` isn't there a way to just fetch id and check if it already exists and not all the data types

Comment: If the `id` is unique then it's sufficient to check only the `id`: `...format: "id == %d", id)`